# What is the importance of the word "inductively"? can I omit it?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Lemma 2.2.2.: For any natural number $n$, $n + 0 = n$.
Note that we cannot deduce this immediately from $0+m = m$
because we do not know yet that $a + b = b + a.$
Proof: We use induction. The base case $0 + 0 = 0$ follows since
we know that $0 + m = m$ for every natural number $m$, and $0$
is a natural number. Now suppose inductively that $n + 0 = n$.
We wish to show that $(n++) + 0 = n++$. But by definition of
addition, $( n++) + 0$ is equal to $( n + 0) ++$, which is equal to $n++$
since $n + 0 = n$. This closes the induction.
what is the meaning of the word "inductively" when it says "suppose inductively"?

Comment: Mathematical induction. It has two parts: (1) when you prove a statement $P(n)$ for $n=0$ and (2) when you assume $P(n)$ and you prove $P(n+1)$. The assumption of the second part is what you wrote as "suppose inductively".

Comment: yes i do know that, i wanted to know if it used because we are using mathematical induction to prove or does it covey something about and why we are assuming?

Comment: You are using mathematical induction. Your $P(n)$ is "$n+0=0$". So you assume that $n+0=0$ for some $n$ and then you prove that $(n+1)+0=0$, or in your nomenclature $(n++)+0=0$ (which is an uncommon notation by the way).

Comment: @freakish I think the $P(n)$ is $n + 0 = n$ and you prove $(n+1)+0=n+1$.  The notation $(n++)$ is not at all uncommon for the successor element in Peano-like systems.  I think $s(n)$ *might* be more common but I personally prefer $n++$.   Any way $n+1$ is clearly a poor choice as that means taking a number $n$ and the number $1$ and performing an advanced operation addition on them.  It doesn't mean the successor of $n$.

Comment: @fleablood if $n+1$ is not a successor, then $n++$ is not a successor as well. The symbol is typically reserved for "increment $n$ by $1$" which is even more complicated operation involving computers and in-place update. Also the meaning of symbols is what majority decides. I've never seen $n++$ used for successor. I've seen many times $n+1$ used for successor. Although I do agree that $s(n)$ is even better, not ambiguous at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the phrase "inductively" in this context is something like this.

The induction step of any induction proof is stated in the following manner:

> If $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is true.

The first portion of this, namely the phrase "$P(n)$ is true", is called the **induction hypothesis**.

In your proof, here's what you actually write to start the proof of the induction step:

> Assume that $P(n)$ is true.

And then you would continue with

> BLAH BLAH BLAH (lots of details of proof) BLAH BLAH BLAH
> therefore $P(n+1)$ is true.

Of course the flexibility of the English language let's you write things in other ways, and that first sentence of that proof can be written in other ways. For instance you might have a more verbose tendency and write

> Assume that the inductive hypothesis $P(n)$ is true.

Or, you might have a less verbose tendency and write

> Assume inductively $P(n)$.

That's all that's going on, its just another way to actually start the proof of the induction step.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is *slightly* strange to say "suppose inductively" and refer to induction when making the hypothesis, and it is more common to say "and then inductively a result follows" and refer to induction while making the step argument.

In this case they are assuming $n+0=n$ as the hypothesis for the induction step.  We assume it with a strategy in mind-- we are going to show $(n++)+0=n++$-- so I think the author means "we are assuming it for inductive purposes".

We are certainly not assuming it in any inductive *manner* which is what an adverb such as "inductive**ly**" would imply.

I personally would use "inductively" when we make an argument. For examply I might say:  "If $b>1$  then $b*b > b*1$ and $b*1>b$ and inductively we can conclude $1 < b < b^2 < .....<b^k < b^{k+1}< ......$"